# Problem with G-5400B Controller OR Rotator

Tags: antenna-rotator

I just acquired a satellite setup consisting of elevation rotor and controller.

The problem I have is that the rotator doesn,t seems to do the full 180 degree!

From 90 degree to 180 degree it goes all the way but if I start from 90 degree going to 0 degree, it stops around 40 degree and it seems to stop at the end limit torque.

I suspect that this rotator was previously open and not replace at his proper position but the previous owner told me that he didn't opened it.

Do you suggest opening the rotator? what should I check if I open it?  what precaution to take?

Comment: What does the manual say? If you have 360 degrees of azimuth rotation, you don't really need 180 degrees of movement from the elevation rotator, 90 is enough, plus some room so it's not too difficult to set up.

Comment: Thank you for your comment tomnexus.  That is what the previous owner told me too but I was suspicious, as I don't have the manual.  I tought that it was supposed  to do 180 degree also.

Comment: The manual for the 5500 (az+el) says something about rotation time for 180 degrees, so maybe that one does.